# Find the latest string based on time and display those

Tags: powershell

I have a text file as shown below:

```
testdatabase-21-07-15-12-00
testdatabase-21-07-15-18-00
testdatabase-21-07-15-23-00
testdatabase-22-07-15-12-00
testdatabase-22-07-15-18-00
testdatabase-22-07-15-23-00
and many more like this (dynamically generated)
```

I am comparing (21/22-07-15) with another text file and if a match is found, I need to see which is the latest one. Like, if match is found for date 21-07-15, I need to retrieve the latest (which is 23) from the many of 21. Same as the case for 22,.... if match is found.

What I have done so far is:

```
$temp = Get-Content "C:\RDS\temp.txt"
foreach($te in $temp) 
{
 $t = $te -split '-'
 $da = $t[1]
 $mo = $t[2]
 $yea = $t[3]
 if("$da-$mo-$yea" -match $temp1)
 {
  # need to write the concept here
 }else
 {
  #nothing
 }
 }
```

How can I get this done.? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need new approach. If parse your file to hashtable then you will be able to receive last date+time by date.

```
# I use string variable for debugging
$temp = "testdatabase-21-07-15-12-00
testdatabase-21-07-15-18-00
testdatabase-21-07-15-19-00
testdatabase-21-07-15-20-00
testdatabase-21-07-15-21-00
testdatabase-21-07-15-23-00
testdatabase-22-07-15-12-00
testdatabase-22-07-15-13-00
testdatabase-22-07-15-14-00
testdatabase-22-07-15-15-00
testdatabase-22-07-15-18-00
testdatabase-22-07-15-23-00" -split "`r`n"

# parse $temp to hashtable by date
$hash = @{}
foreach ($te in $temp) {
    if ($te -match "testdatabase-(\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)") {
        [Array]$hash[$Matches[1]] += $te
    }
}
```

Now `$hash` look like:

```
Name       Value
----       -----        
21-07-15   testdatabase-21-07-15-12-00
           testdatabase-21-07-15-18-00
           testdatabase-21-07-15-19-00
           testdatabase-21-07-15-20-00
           testdatabase-21-07-15-21-00
           testdatabase-21-07-15-23-00

22-07-15   testdatabase-22-07-15-12-00
           testdatabase-22-07-15-13-00
           testdatabase-22-07-15-14-00
           testdatabase-22-07-15-15-00
           testdatabase-22-07-15-18-00
           testdatabase-22-07-15-23-00
```

After these manipulations you can access to array by key like `<day>-<month>-<year>` and get latest element from it:

```
$temp1 = "21-07-15"

if ($hash.ContainsKey($temp1)) {
    $array = $hash[$temp1]    
    # last element in array
    $last = $array[$array.Length - 1]

    Write-Host $last -ForegroundColor Blue
}
```

Output:

```
testdatabase-21-07-15-23-00
```

Comment: But I wont know what all dates are there in that dynamic file. If that is the case how can I say $temp1 = " somevalue " exactly...

Answer (score 0):

I used a custom object to organize the list with 3 properties: filename, full date, date only. The date values are cast and stored as actual [datetime] vars. With that true time, you can use native powershell grouping and sorting functions to get the most recent file for each day.

I'm located in the US, where my OS defaults to mm/dd/yy. If your region has different defaults, you may need to adjust the right side of the var assignment for $dateFull and $dateOnly.

```
$crossref = @()
gc dates.txt | foreach {
    ($name, $day, $month, $year, $hour, $minute) = $_.split("-")
    $dateFull = [datetime]"$month/$day/$year $hour`:$minute"
    $dateOnly = [datetime]"$month/$day/$year"
    $crossref += New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{"fileName" = $_; "dateFull" = $dateFull; "dateOnly" = $dateOnly;}
}
# raw unsorted data from our new object
$crossref | ft -a

# most recent file for each day
$crossref | group-object dateOnly | foreach {$_.Group | Sort-Object dateFull | Select-Object -Last 1} | fl

PS C:\temp> .\fault.ps1
dateFull           dateOnly          fileName
--------           --------          --------
7/21/2015 23:00:00 7/21/2015 0:00:00 testdatabase-21-07-15-23-00
7/22/2015 23:00:00 7/22/2015 0:00:00 testdatabase-22-07-15-23-00
7/21/2015 12:00:00 7/21/2015 0:00:00 testdatabase-21-07-15-12-00
7/21/2015 18:00:00 7/21/2015 0:00:00 testdatabase-21-07-15-18-00
7/22/2015 12:00:00 7/22/2015 0:00:00 testdatabase-22-07-15-12-00
7/22/2015 18:00:00 7/22/2015 0:00:00 testdatabase-22-07-15-18-00

dateFull : 7/21/2015 23:00:00
dateOnly : 7/21/2015 0:00:00
fileName : testdatabase-21-07-15-23-00

dateFull : 7/22/2015 23:00:00
dateOnly : 7/22/2015 0:00:00
fileName : testdatabase-22-07-15-23-00
```